# Cross Stack Reference in Parameters Section

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to figure out how to pass output of a CloudFormation stack as a parameter to another CloudFormation stack, particularly via the [Parameters section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) of the CloudFormation definition.

Say StackA is exporting an output :-

```
Outputs:
  TargetGroupArn:
    Description: "Target Group ARN"
    Export: {Name: TargetGroupArn}
    Value: {Ref: TargetGroup}
```

Can StackB contain a parameter in it's definition :-

```
Parameters:
  TargetGroupArn:
     Type: String
     Default: 
       Fn::ImportValue: TargetGroupArn
```

---

**Note:** I'm aware that `TargetGroupArn` can be fetched wherever required in the Resources section via `Fn::ImportValue`. I'm specifically interested in importing in the parameters section.

Comment: Have you tried it?  what result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot import the value as the parameter default.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) (emphasis added),

> You can use intrinsic functions only in specific parts of a template.
>   Currently, you can use intrinsic functions in **resource properties**,
>   **outputs**, **metadata attributes**, and **update policy attributes**. You can
>   also use intrinsic functions to conditionally create stack resources.

Parameters are not one of the parts that allow the use of intrinsic functions; and as `Fn::ImportValue` is an intrinsic function, a parameter value cannot be imported.